# Как считать строки из файла в массив стринговский или в вектор в С++?

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы, вектор

Как считать строки из файла в массив стринговский или в вектор в С++? У меня есть файл в котором на каждой строчке записаны пути к каким-то файлам. Как все эти пути записать в стринговский массив или в вектор?

Comment: Как насчет вектора стрингов?)

Comment: @free_ze я не против)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой вариант, без учета ошибок чтения:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
{
    std::ifstream f("file.txt");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(f, line))
        lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::ifstream input;

input.open("file.txt");

while (!input.eof())
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(input, s);
    v.push_back(s);
}

input.close();
```

Comment: `while (!input.eof())` - и вот тут вы получите ерунду в последней (лишней) строке...